# Symfony 1.4 Is there a way to escape all objects (e.g. objects of forms) in views?

Tags: security, escaping, symfony-1.4

Example Action

```
$object = new myObject();
$object->setName("Darth <b>Vader</b>");
$this->form = new myObjectForm($object)
```

Now in view:

```
echo $form->getObject()->getName();
```

This will output the name NOT escaped.

So ok, I can change the action to:

```
$this->object = new myObject();
$this->object->setName("Darth <b>Vader</b>");
$this->form = new myObjectForm($this->object)
```

And now in view:

```
echo $object->getName();
```

this will output the name escaped, wonderful ;)

But, is there an automatic way to get $form->getObject()->getName() escaped as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the object directly from Form it is not escaped automatic, you should pass objects that need to be escaped in view by the action:

```
$this->object = $this->form->getObject();
```

Eventually if you really need to do that in the view, you can pass the object from Form to ObjectDecorator for escaping it:

```
$escaped = new sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator(ESC_SPECIALCHARS,$form->getObject());
echo $escaped->getName(); // Will return escaped value
```

Comment: thanks! :) I'm using sfOutputEscaper::escape(ESC_ENTITIES, $object) now